# Setting MSP-430 toolchain in linux

Tags: msp430, development-tools, launchpad

Can anybody please guide procedure to setup tool-chain for MSP430 in Linux (particularly Ubuntu)? I am using MSP430 launchpad (MSP-EXP430G2), and I need to setup compiler/build tools and debugger drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the tools are in your apt repository:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-msp430 msp430-libc mspdebug msp430mcu
```

And if you want to do debugging:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gdb-msp430
```

Better still, install either Energia (the "official" IDE for the Launchpad) or the more advanced UECIDE.

Comment: Can i use code composer studio with gcc-msp430 ?

Comment: code composer studio will most likely install/utilize any available toolchains as appropriate for the target

Comment: where can i get information about commands to compile and build source code for gcc-msp430 ?

Comment: Best bet - install Energia and use the verbose compilation mode to look at what commands it runs with what parameters.  But at the end of the day it's just GCC - nothing special about it really.